# Use a global variable to keep track of progression of a multiprocessing program

Tags: python, multiprocessing, counter

I got a program that I ran in multiprocessing. I would like to have a progression system with a print.

This is what I came up with:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os

global counter
global size

def f(x):
    global counter
    global size
    print ("{} / {}".format(counter, size))
    counter += 1
    return x**2

size = 4
counter = 1

result = list()
for x in [1,2,3,4]:
    result.append(f(x))
```

This one works. However, if you replace the bottom part with:

```
with mp.Pool(processes = 2) as p:
    p.starmap(f, [1,2,3,4])
```

It doesn't. I don't understand why, can anyone help to get that up and running ? Thanks :)

*N.B: This is of course a dummy example.*

EDIT:

Ok new issue appear with your solution. I'll make an example:

```
fix1 = 1
fix2 = 2
dynamic = [1,2,3,4,5]

def f(x, y, z):
    return x**2 + y + z

size = len(dynamic)
counter = 1

with mp.Pool(processes = 2) as p:
    for output in p.starmap(f, [(x, fix1, fix2) for x in dynamic]):
        print ("{} / {}".format(counter, size))
        counter += 1
```

This one works but does all the print at the end.

```
with mp.Pool(processes = 2) as p:
    for output in p.imap_unordered(f, [(x, fix1, fix2) for x in dynamic]):
        print ("{} / {}".format(counter, size))
        counter += 1
```

This one doesn't work and say that f() is missing 2 required positional arguments fix1 and fix2.

Any idea why I get this behavior?

N.B: I'm running on windows.

Comment: That gives "int object is not iterable" because `starmap` tries to unpack each of the integers. Did you want `p.map`? That will fail also because the subprocesses do not share the same memory (on linux, you get a copy-on-write view of parent memory, but as soon as you write the variable, whatever memory pages were touched were copied by the operating system).

Answer (score 2):

On a forking system like linux, subprocesses share a copy-on-write view of the parent memory space. If one side updates memory, it gets its own private copy of the changed pages. On other systems, a new process is created and a new python is executed. In either case, neither side sees the changes the others make. And that means that everyone is updating their own private copy of `count` and don't see the additions made by the others.

To keep things complicated, `stdout` is not synchronized. If workers print, you re likely to get garbled messages.

An alternative is to count the results as they come back to the parent pool. The parent tracks the count and the parent is the only one printing. If you don't care about the order of the returned data, then `imap_unordered` will work well for you.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def f(x):
    return x**2

data = [1,2,3,4]
result = []

with mp.Pool(processes = 2) as p:
    for val in p.imap_unordered(f, data):
        result.append(val)
        print("progress",  len(result)/len(data))
```

Comment: Perfect, that explains the issue I had. Surprisingly the starmap was working for me, although I did that dummy example really fast. I'm gonna try your fix :)

Comment: Can you have a look at the EDIT, I ran into an issue when trying to implement your proposition :/